# Checking property equivalence in OWL ontology through SWRL or SQWRL

Tags: owl, semantic-web, swrl, sqwrl

I have properties **P1, P2** and **P3**. **P1** is equivalent to intersection of **P2** and **P3**.
How do I write a rule that takes **P1** and finds intersection of **P2** and **P3** as equivalent property.

I know SWRL works only on A-Box Individuals. Any hack here? Or am I missing some alternative ways?

Any help in designing such a rule is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Most likely, your question is interesting, but I can't understand it. Do you need OWL axiom that acts similar to something like `P1(?a, ?b) -> P2(?a, ?b) ^ P3(?a, ?b)`?

Comment: Thanks for comment @StanislavKralin! First question: Is it possible to model in protege object properties tab? If not, the above mentioned rule could be handy. However, P2 and P3 could work on different domain and ranges! Do you have any comment?

Comment: First, try to declare P1 as subproperty of both P2 and P3.

Comment: OK.. I will check if that t-box knowledge is accessible using OWLAPI in my application.. SWRLAPI does not have property equivalence axioms [link](https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi/wiki/SWRLTBoxBuiltInLibrary)

Comment: OWL API has support for all axioms of OWL 2 standard. there is no explicit intersection of properties possible, the only way is to use multiple subproperty axioms as suggested above.